# Narrowing down search using conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, toad

Trying to do a very narrow search using #SLQ in #TOAD for over 12 million records, while expecting results of 150 records.
Have following:

```
-Account  CODE  Product Amount
 1        100   001     10
 1        120   002     5
 1        130   003     20
 2        100   001     30
 2        130   003     10
 3        130   003     20
```

Tried:

```
select *
from table
group by Account, CODE, Product, Amount
having CODE in (100,130)
```

But in the results I get account 1, which shouldn't be the case, as I need only accounts with 100 and 100/130 combination

Need to get accounts with only code 130, and second search only accounts with code 100 and 130.

But everything I tried is resulting with accounts that include code 100 or 130, like account 1.

Tried group by and then applying having, tried inserting conditions on where clause.
But always accounts are included in results that have code 100 and 130 in their data, and are no only with codes 100 and 130.

Comment: Show what you have tried so far.  It's also not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: Here are some tips on how to structure your question better: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/460557

Comment: Tried: Select * from table where code = 100. But its populating account 1 as well, which I dont need, as I need account with 100 code only or 100/130 code combination

Answer (score 0):

Would this help? Sample data in lines #1 - 12; query you might be interested in begins at line #13.

```
SQL> with test (account, code, product, amount) as
  2    (select 1, 100, '001', 10 from dual union all
  3     select 1, 120, '002',  5 from dual union all
  4     select 1, 130, '003', 20 from dual union all
  5     --
  6     select 2, 100, '001', 30 from dual union all
  7     select 2, 130, '003', 10 from dual union all
  8     --
  9     select 3, 130, '003', 20 from dual union all
 10     --
 11     select 4, 200, '001', 10 from dual union all
 12     select 4, 100, '002', 20 from dual
 13    )
 14  select * from test
 15  where account in (select account
 16                    from test
 17                    group by account
 18                    having count(distinct code) <= 2
 19                       and min(code) in (100, 130)
 20                       and max(code) in (100, 130)
 21                   );

   ACCOUNT       CODE PRO     AMOUNT
---------- ---------- --- ----------
         2        130 003         10
         2        100 001         30
         3        130 003         20

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you for trying. The thing is that I need to search in 12 mil records and can not type them all to make union. Thanks

Comment: Didn't you see what I wrote? The first 13 lines represent sample data in a form of a CTE (Common Table Expression a.k.a. the WITH factoring clause). If you provided proper test case (CREATE TABLE and INSERT INTO statements), I wouldn't have to create sample by myself. All that you already have in your table so - no, you wouldn't type 12 million unions. Query you do need begins at line #14.

Comment: Oh ok, understood. Apologies for not writing as clear as it should be, still new into the sql. The thing is that i am not creating tables or having privileges of inserting. Basically need to query on given table. But will certainly try and use your example. Thanks again